# Django -- Can't import foreign databases unless they're default

Tags: python, django

I have a database `bonds.db` which I would like to import as an alternative database. My default database is `database.sqlite3`. My problem is that I can't import `bonds.db` unless I set it as my default database.

I import it by typing `python manage.py inspectdb --database=bonds`, and I paste the output into the `models.py` of a new app that I created. Then I type `python manage.py syncdb --database=bonds`. This works flawlessly if bonds is the default database, but Django imports an empty database if `bonds.db` is not the default database.

Let me know what information you need.

Comment: could you share your database settings from `settings.py` file?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I have solved it. Refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and it's an obvious one: Database routing. You need to create a `routers.py` file and add this to your `settings.py`:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['myapp1.routers.name-of-your-routers.py-class',
                    'myapp2.routers.name-of-your-routers.py-class']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'myapp1': 'mydb1', 
                         'myapp2': 'mydb2'}
```

Djangosnippets has the `routers.py` file: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2687/

You need do add an attribute called `in_db = 'desired-db'` to the `Meta` class of every class in your `models.py`.